# Hyper-V backup - manual copy OK?

Tags: backup, hyper-v

TL;DR: Is it safe to backup a Hyper-V virtual machine manually by simply copying the files, provided that the virtual machine is turned off at that time?

I have a Hyper-V virtual machine which consists of a series of checkpoints: basically, I would install the operating system and create a checkpoint, then changed the OS settings and create a checkpoint, then install an application and create a checkpoint, etc. Each checkpoint was made while the virtual machine was turned off. Unfortunately, somewhere along the way a bad checkpoint was created which now prevents a regular Export from the Hyper-V Manager - I am getting an unspecified error 0x800040005. The machine itself can start and works fine, but I can't export it.

My eventual goal is to merge all the checkpoints into one, discarding the installation history. But before I perform any drastic changes such as this, I want to be certain that I can restore the working machine if something goes wrong. Also, I would find it useful to be able to backup my machines on my own, without involving the Hyper-V infrastructure.

Comment: At worst, you should be able to build a new virtual machine around the VHD/VHDX file. You could try it, to get rid of the bad checkpoints. Question: What is the entire text of the 0x80004005 error?

Comment: If I rebuild the machine, I expect I will lose the activation of Windows and other software, that's why I want to have a fully working backup first before I go into these things. --

The actual message doesn't really tell much else: If I translate it from my local language, it just says: Export of the virtual machine failed. Error occurred: Unspecified error (0x80004005).

Comment: As long as you keep the same virtual hardware for the VM, it will stay activated. Activation will only be lost for a major change of hardware, for example another motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments with my original VM, I can conclude that **Yes**, it is possible to backup a virtual machine by copying as long as the machine is turned off, however, there are several caveats:

1. One needs to be careful to copy **all** of the files that comprise the virtual machine. That includes the harddisk images (`.vhdx`, `.avhdx`), the virtual machine description files (`.vmcx`, `.vmgs`, `.vmrs`) and the snapshots. Each of these can be located in a different directory.
2. Such a machine can be restored on a different computer **provided that it isn't broken** like mine; if it **is** broken, the import will fail to find the snapshots and apparently Hyper-V won't give you an option to recover what it can - it either recovers all the checkpoints or none of them.

However, I was able to fix my broken machine by following these steps:

1. Copy all of the files of the broken machine to another computer.
2. Extract them on another computer **twice** (to get two copies of the same files).
3. Use the first copy for import. The import will fail to recover the checkpoints, but that's OK. Note that many of the files get deleted in the process.
4. Merge the files from the second copy into one, preferably using PowerShell: Find the newest `.avhdx` file, then merge it using command `Merge-VM -Path the_newest_checkpoint.avhdx -DestinationPath the_main_image.vhdx`. This will merge all of the checkpoint disks up to (and including) the newest one into the main file.
5. Attach the new combined `.vhdx` file to the imported machine.
6. Export the machine to get a **working** backup.
7. Verify that the contents are actually intact.
8. Copy the working backup back to the original machine, delete the damaged VM and import the fixed one.